# Getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Object" error at the time of initiation of integer inside Object Array in java

Tags: java

```
public class objArrayPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object ar []= new Object [4];
        ar[0]= 12;
    }
}
```

when I write ar[0]= 12; I am getting the error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Object"

Comment: What are the java compiler versions used on both computers?

Comment: What's the difference between the two machines? Different version of Java, perhaps? Make sure you upgrade your java on your home machine.

Comment: Btw this should compile fine and that is the right behavior. So whatever compiler you are using at your home is wrong. It is possible that it is a pre java 5 compiler

Comment: Change `int[] ar` to `Integer[] ar`. It will solve your issue.

Comment: The compiler knows that `ar` elements should be objects and you supply it an `int` - it just doesn't know how to auto-box (either the JDK itself is too old or you set the source level to < 1.5) and thus it complains. Change `ar` to `Integer[]` or use `ar[0] = Integer.valueOf(12);` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

To convert `12` into an object you need al least Java 1.5, this is called **Autoboxing**

> Autoboxing and unboxing was introduced in Java 1.5 to automatically  convert primitive type into boxed primitive( Object or Wrapper class)

So be sure to have on both machines a Java version >= 1.5

Comment: Great help. Thanks a LOT. I just changed the java compiler compliance level from 1.4 to 1.6 and its working fine now. Thanks again

Comment: Great as it works for you you should accept the aswer to let further readers know that this is the solution...